# refactoring sql while loop to regular inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization, query-optimization

I am inserting parent records and child records at the same time in a stored procedure.

Rather than have outside code make nested calls to create each parent and then each child of that parent (which is even slower than my current approach), I am giving the sql a comma separated list of child types that I put into a temp table (#TempParentChildUpdateTable) which is associated with a parent record in a table value parameter (@PenguinParentChildUpdate).

Then I loop through both, insert the parent and then insert all related children.

The problem is this while loop is not performing very well at 13 requests per second.

How do I make this faster? How do I take out the while loop?

Is there a way to do this with non-looping inserts? If so, can the string parsing happen inside the inner insert?

```
DECLARE @RowCnt int = 0;
DECLARE @CounterId int = 1;
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM @PenguinParentChildUpdate;
WHILE @CounterId <= @RowCnt
BEGIN
    SELECT @GrandparentId = WorkflowInstanceId,
        @ParentType = ParentType,
        @ChildIds = ChildIds
        FROM @PenguinParentChildUpdate

    -- insert parent record

    INSERT INTO WorkflowInstanceRole (ParentType, GrandparentId)
        VALUES(@ParentType, @GrandparentId)
    SET @ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                
    -- identify children

    -- convert comma separated list (e.g. 4,91,12,6) into separate rows

    INSERT INTO #TempParentChildUpdateTable (sq.ChildId, sq.ParentId)
        select convert(int, value) ChildId, @ParentId RoleId FROM string_split(@ChildIds, CHAR(44))

    -- insert children 7787+ =
    IF (@ChildIds IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ChildIds))) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.PenguinParentChild
        (
            grandparentId,
            childid,
        )
        select
            @ParentId,
            childId,
        from
            #TempParentChildUpdateTable tsru
        where
            tsru.ParentId = @ParentId
    END

    SET @CounterId = @CounterId + 1
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling to follow some of the logic in the loop, but I think the premise is

1. Insert to WorkFlowInstanceRole
2. Capture the inserted records then insert further children based on this.

Since step 2 requires data that is not in `WorkFlowInstanceRole` you need to use `MERGE` to add the new rows, rather than a standard insert. What this allows you to do is capture the `ChildIds` from the source table, even though you aren't inserting them. Something like this should do it (I've had to guess at some data types):

```
DECLARE @Output TABLE 
(   
    ParentId INT, 
    ParentType INT, 
    GrandParentId INT, 
    ChildIDs VARCHAR(MAX)
);

MERGE INTO WorkflowInstanceRole AS t
USING @PenguinParentChildUpdate AS s
    ON 1 = 0 -- Will never be true so will always insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (ParentType, GrandparentId)
    VALUES (s.ParentType, s.WorkflowInstanceId)
OUTPUT inserted.ParentId, inserted.ParentType, inserted.GrandParentId, s.ChilDIds
    INTO @Output (ParentId,ParentType, GrandParentId, ChildIDs);

INSERT INTO dbo.PenguinParentChild (GrandParentId, ChildId)
SELECT  o.ParentId,
        CONVERT(int, ss.value) 
FROM    @Output AS o
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(i.ChileIds, CHAR(44)) AS ss;
```

The key part is the `MERGE`* really, since the condition is `1=0` then this will always insert. Unlike `INSERT` the `OUTPUT` clause on a merge will allow you to capture both the newly inserted identity value, and the non-inserted `ChildIds` column.

This is output into a temporary table, which you can then use, along with `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT()` to insert the child records.

There may be some data errors, and logic may not be 100% perfect, but this should hopefully be a bit step in the right direction.

---

<sup>*`MERGE` has a [number of known bugs](https://michaeljswart.com/2021/08/what-to-avoid-if-you-want-to-use-merge/), and I'd generally advise to steer clear, but I am not aware of any alternative that would allow you to capture the newly inserted identity value, and the non-inserted `ChildIds` column, and as far as I am aware none of these bugs affect this operation (Anecdotally, in that I have never encountered an issue using this method).</sup>

---

Comment: I didn't test the full solution, but after banging my head against this and reading your solution I understood what the need for APPLY was, which I have used basically never (in spite of getting a hard MS SQL certification). I will also familiarize myself with merge.